# How to solve the errors when using pip install Pillow

Tags: python-3.x, debian, orange-pi

"pip install Pillow" got error!

I installed Debian system on Orange Pie zero

(http://www.orangepi.org/download resources/orangepizero/2016-11-24/orangepizero_3cf6c296784e7ae2cd8cb.html)

---

Linux OrangePizero 3.4.39 #2 SMP PREEMPT Mon Nov 21 16:23:11 CST 2016 armv7l 
GNU/Linux

Python 3.4.2

pip 1.5.6 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.4)

---

When I installed pillow with pip3, I encountered the following error

```sh
Downloading/unpacking Pillow
  Downloading Pillow-6.1.0.tar.gz (33.8MB): 33.8MB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-build-g2pkqhvw/Pillow/setup.py) egg_info for package Pillow
    /usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py:260: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'python_requires'
      warnings.warn(msg)

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-g2pkqhvw/Pillow/setup.py", line 873, in <module>
        zip_safe=not (debug_build() or PLATFORM_MINGW),
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "<string>", line 15, in replacement_run
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 193, in find_sources
        mm.run()
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 277, in run
        self.add_defaults()
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 306, in add_defaults
        sdist.add_defaults(self)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/sdist.py", line 183, in add_defaults
        build_ext = self.get_finalized_command('build_ext')
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/cmd.py", line 299, in get_finalized_command
        cmd_obj.ensure_finalized()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/cmd.py", line 107, in ensure_finalized
        self.finalize_options()
      File "/tmp/pip-build-g2pkqhvw/Pillow/setup.py", line 324, in finalize_options
        if sys.version_info.major >= 3 and not self.parallel:
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/cmd.py", line 103, in __getattr__
        raise AttributeError(attr)
    AttributeError: parallel
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    running egg_info

creating pip-egg-info/Pillow.egg-info

writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/Pillow.egg-info/dependency_links.txt

writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/Pillow.egg-info/top_level.txt

writing pip-egg-info/Pillow.egg-info/PKG-INFO

writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'

/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py:260: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'python_requires'

  warnings.warn(msg)

warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found



Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>

  File "/tmp/pip-build-g2pkqhvw/Pillow/setup.py", line 873, in <module>

    zip_safe=not (debug_build() or PLATFORM_MINGW),

  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup

    dist.run_commands()

  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands

    self.run_command(cmd)

  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command

    cmd_obj.run()

  File "<string>", line 15, in replacement_run

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 193, in find_sources

    mm.run()

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 277, in run

    self.add_defaults()

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 306, in add_defaults

    sdist.add_defaults(self)

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/sdist.py", line 183, in add_defaults

    build_ext = self.get_finalized_command('build_ext')

  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/cmd.py", line 299, in get_finalized_command

    cmd_obj.ensure_finalized()

  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/cmd.py", line 107, in ensure_finalized

    self.finalize_options()

  File "/tmp/pip-build-g2pkqhvw/Pillow/setup.py", line 324, in finalize_options

    if sys.version_info.major >= 3 and not self.parallel:

  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/cmd.py", line 103, in __getattr__

    raise AttributeError(attr)

AttributeError: parallel
```

I hope to solve this problem.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Use Python 3.5+ or older version of Pillow. Python 3.4 is retired:

https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/3581